# Is the line-input volume control linear-taper or audio-taper?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

The input-volume sound GUI slider appears to be a linear-taper instead of an audio-taper (aka: logarithmic scale). If I adjust the volume to adjust the input gain level it is very, very sensitive. It is not like my professional audio mixer slider.

Is there a way to display the dB scale along the bottom of the input volume control in the system GUI?